# Raw controller with XML layout

Tags: magento2, controllers

I have a Raw Controller where i load products in based on a search. Now i need this to be without JS and css (therefor the RAW type) because i will load that into my page later on with ajax.

This is the fastest way that i came up with to do this.

BUT , It is really hard to implement blocks and childblocks into the Raw Controller. I would prefer it much more if i could use an XML for that.

So how would i do that exactly?

**Code now :**

```
 public function execute()
    {
   $layout = $this->_template->getLayout();

        $html = '<div class="container mx-auto productsrow">';
        $html .= '<div class="row no-gutters">';
        $html .= $this->_template->setAttribute("class", 'page-products')->toHtml();
 $html .= $layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Search\Products')->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::searchproducts.phtml')->toHtml();
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';



        $this->_translateInline->processResponseBody($html);

        $result = $this->_resultRawFactory->create();
        $result->setContents($html);

        return $result;
}
```

As you can see i need to manually create blocks etc to have in my controller since its a raw controller.

*But isn't here a way how to have a raw controller but still use an XML OR use a page controller but exclude all css/js so the page loads really fast.*

Answer (score 1):

You can to use layout handle in the custom controller (replace $handle and $blockName to your values):

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory */
protected $pageFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
) {
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $page */
    $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
    $page->addHandle($handle); // for example, wishlist_index_index

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $block */
    $block = $page->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName); // block name in the layout

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $result */
    $result = $this->resultFactory->create($this->resultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
    $result->setContents($block ? $block->toHtml() : '');

    return $result;
}
```

I'm not sure this approach most correct and fastest, but it is works very well on my ajax requests.
Write me if you'll have any issues.

Comment: I actually found a really nice solution myself that i will post later on. But thanks for you input!

Answer (score 0):

What i end up doing was the following :

```
 public function execute()
    {
   $layout = $this->_template->getLayout();
        $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('search_custom');
        $layout->generateXml();
  $html = '<div class="row no-gutters">';
        $html .= $layout->getOutput();
        $html .= '</div>';
 $result = $this->_resultRawFactory->create();
        $result->setContents($html);

        return $result;
    }
```

You can do all kind of neat things with this like lets say we have the next search_custom.xml (you need to have the custom page layout search_custom since we add that handle) :
**search_custom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
<attribute name="class" value="page-products"/>
        <container name="content">
                <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" name="search_result_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <!-- If argument's position depends on image size changeable in VDE:
                        positions:list-secondary,grid-secondary,list-actions,grid-actions,list-primary,grid-primary
                    -->
                        <argument name="positioned" xsi:type="string">positions:list-secondary</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="catalogsearch.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="catalogsearch.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
        </container>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Index.php adjusted:**

```
/**
 * function with my own custom search with getList() and filters to get the right product collection
 *
 */
$products = $this->_products->getProducts($_GET['inputvalue']);
$idarray = array();

/*
 * Abstract collection uses ID's so we get all the ID's
 */
foreach ($products as $product){
    $productid = $product->getId();
    if (isset($productid)) {
        $idarray[] = $productid;
    }
}

/**
 * use the ID's to create a new product collection
 */
$productcollection =
    $this->productCollection
        ->addIdFilter($idarray)
        ->addFieldToSelect('*');

$list = $layout->getBlock('search_result_list');
/**
 * We can set the product collection with our own
 */
$list->setProductCollection($productcollection);
$list->setUseToolbar(false);
```